# React Event Handlers not firing when using code from npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, reactjs, browserify

I made a jsx file with a React component. I can require locally and everything works fine. However, when I use the version I published to npm by doing `npm install react-tabs-component`, rendering works none of the event handlers fire. No errors or warnings.

I don't think there's anything wrong with the code, because it works locally and it passes a thorough test suite.

I think I must have done something wrong with my package.json:

```
    {
      "name": "react-tabs-component",
      "version": "1.1.1",
      "description": "Tabs Component for React with the simplest API",
      "keywords": [
        "React",
        "tabs",
        "tab",
        "component"
      ],
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/mheiber/react-tabs-component"
      },
      "main": "Tabs.js",
      "dependencies": {
        "envify": "^3.4.0",
        "react": "^0.12.0",
        "reactify": "^1.1.0"
      },
      "author": "Max Heiber",
      "browserify": {
        "transform": [
          "reactify"
        ]
      },
      "scripts": {
        "test": "jest"
      },
      "jest": {
        "rootDir": "./",
        "scriptPreprocessor": "./jest-preprocessor.js",
        "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
          "react",
          "./node_modules/react/"
        ]
      },
  "devDependencies": {
        "jest-cli": "0.4.0",
        "react-tools": "0.13.1",
        "reactify": "1.1.0"
      },
      "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/mheiber/react-tabs-component/issues"
      },
      "homepage": "https://github.com/mheiber/react-tabs-component",
      "directories": {
        "example": "examples"
      },
     "license": "ISC"
     }
```

and here is a simplified version of the code from package:

```
var React = require('react/addons');

var getChildrenArray = function(context){
    var children = [];
    React.Children.forEach(context.props.children,function(child){
        children.push(child);
    });
    return children;
};

var noop = function(){};

var Tabs = React.createClass({
    propTypes:{
        defaultTabNum: React.PropTypes.number,
    },
    getDefaultProps: function(){
        return {
            defaultTabNum: 0
        };
    },
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {activeTabNum: this.props.defaultTabNum};
    },
    setActiveTabNum: function(num,callback){
        this.setState({activeTabNum: num},callback);
    },
    getActiveTabNum: function(){
        return this.state.activeTabNum;
    },
    _change: function(e){
        this.setActiveTabNum(newActiveTabNum,callback);
    },
    render: function(){
        var children = getChildrenArray(this);
        var activeTabContent = children[this.state.activeTabNum];

        var tabs = this.props.tabNames.map(function(tabName,tabNum){
            var isActive = (tabNum === this.state.activeTabNum);
            return (
                <span 
                    key={'tab-'+tabNum}
                    data-tabnum={tabNum}
                    onClick={this._change}
                >
                    {tabName}
                </span>

                    );
        }.bind(this));

        return (
            <div>
            <nav>{tabs}</nav>
            {activeTabContent}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Tabs;
```

And here is the code that works when Tabs.js is in the same directory, but not when I use the version that is in node_modules when I `npm install`:

```
var Tabs=require('react-tabs-component');
var React=require('react');

React.render(
  <Tabs tabNames={[1, 2, 3]}>
    <p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p>
  </Tabs>,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

I'm using Browserify and Reactify.

I know I might be down-voted for posting this much code, but I didn't want to test by junking up npm with a lot of packages that don't work.

Comment: This question appears to be related to the js library react and not he php library of the same name.  I have updated the tag accordingly.  If I am mistaken, feel free to revert.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Thanks! You're right that it's the js library.

Comment: Is it rendering the same content with the only difference being the click handlers aren't working? Your mapping function doing it's job? Feels like the onClick isn't getting bound correctly.

Comment: @badAdviceGuy it's like you describe: the content is rendering identically, the only difference is that the click handler isn't called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a linked component peerDepdencies use the equivalent node\_modules of the script being linked to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33437271/how-to-make-a-linked-component-peerdepdencies-use-the-equivalent-node-modules-of)