# How to make a linked component peerDepdencies use the equivalent node_modules of the script being linked to?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

- I am using [npm](/questions/tagged/npm) version 3 (version relevant because of [the new way `peerDependencies` behave in version 3](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5875)).
- I have a [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) app called "game" and a [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) component called "player".
- I am using `webpack-dev-server` to run "game" app.
- `react` and `react-dom` are dependencies of `game` app and `peerDependencies` of the `player` component.

I would like to link `player` component to `game` app.

I have done:

```bash
cd /player
npm link
cd /game
npm link player
```

When I run `webpack-dev-server` program, I get the following error message:

```
Hash: 09968e7401389f50049f
Version: webpack 1.12.2
Time: 339ms
chunk    {0} app.js, 0.14192ce06d8b6f8abb91.hot-update.js, app.css (app) 2.32 MB
     + 576 hidden modules

ERROR in ../player/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react' in /player
 @ ../player/index.js 21:13-29
```

How do I make `player` component to use `game` `./node_modules` for the `peerDependences`?

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of digging, I have found a solution in the webpack documentation: [`npm link`ed modules doesn’t find their dependencies](https://webpack.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#npm-linked-modules-doesn-t-find-their-dependencies).

Simply add `resolve.fallback` (and `resolveLoader.fallback` if your dependencies have loader specific logic, such as using CSS Modules) to your webpack config:

```js
resolve: {
    fallback: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules')
},
resolveLoader: {
    fallback: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules')
}
```

The `fallback` setting will make webpack loader look into the local `./node_modules` path for any dependencies that cannot be resolved, including the dependencies of the dependencies of the main app itself. As a result, all `peerDependencies` of the main app dependencies will be resolved against the main app `./node_modules`.