# npm link with webpack - cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, nvm

I'm trying to npm link a module to a project using webpack as its bundler. Of course, after trying many things, I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/store/TableView.jsx
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-bootstrap-table'
```

Here are the exact steps I take when doing this:

```
1.) cd ../forks/react-bootstrap-table
2.) npm link
(success, checked ~/.nvm/.../node_modules/react-bootstrap-table for symlink and it's there)
3.) cd ../../projRoot/
4.) npm link react-bootstrap-table
(no errors thrown?, says successful link)
5.) node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
```

**Solutions I've tried:**
  - https://webpack.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html
  - [How to make a linked component peerDepdencies use the equivalent node_modules of the script being linked to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33437271/how-to-make-a-linked-component-peerdepdencies-use-the-equivalent-node-modules-of)
  - And many purple links on google serps

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const ROOT_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname)

module.exports = {
  devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '' : 'source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: ['react-hot','babel']
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ['style','css','sass'],
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loaders: ['style','css']
    },
    {
      test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
      loader: 'file-loader'
    }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    fallback: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules')
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    fallback: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules')
  },
  output: {
    path: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'app/dist') : path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'app/build'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(ROOT_PATH),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    progress: true,
    stats: 'errors-only',
    host: '192.168.1.115'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
}
```

**Notes:**
  1. this is the only symlink in the project
  2. I run npm install inside forked version (also tried without, doesn't work)
  3. I use NVM, but I have used symlinks before without webpack successfully.

I've been at this for a few days now, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Me too.  Nuts there is no existing answer to be found.  The problem is obvious - babel/webpack doesn't follow or accomodate symlinks

Comment: This is sort of a show stopper for me.  I develop multiple supporting libraries for my applications in tandem with my applications, and it is looking like I will need to find an alternative to webpack to support this workflow.

Comment: fun fact: webpack **does not work** with npm link. It's "well documented" but @#$*( hard to find. https://webpack.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#npm-linked-modules-doesn-t-find-their-dependencies. We've run into this so often we stopped using npm link altogether: if you have a fork, either point to `require('../../../yourfork')` with as many `../` as you need to get to the fork dir, or alternatively, point to your own fork with a github link instead of an npm semver, or (and we've started doing this) just literally copy your fork into the node_modules dir for dev work.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans And what if you want to debug the forked module? Is it okay? I'm trying to debug something, and I can copy it, but in vscode I cannot debug it.

Comment: Usually better to write your own additional tests inside your own forked repo dir instead of trying to debug "through" another project.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I was facing a similar issue with `webpack` and ended up by adding this my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        symlinks: false
    }
};
```

Here is the link to [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-symlinks). Since your question there happened a lot to `webpack` and their api, so I do not know how much relevance my answer still has according to your question. But for people facing this or a similar issue today this could be a solution. As to be seen, there are still people complaining about:

- Webpack GitHub [Issue 1643](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1643)
- Webpack GitHub [Issue 1866](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1866)

Comment: Reading comments from others, this has the downside that it breaks HMR, so while the application runs, it will not reload when the dependency is updated in its original location.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure you have bundle and yarn installed and executed in the linked package

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it's useful for others, the solution of adding the `resolve.symlinks` configuration to `false` [suggested by @Beat](http://#48582767) was not enough in my case, I had to perform the following steps to solve it:

**In the library**:

1. Setup the libraries that are generating issues as `peerDependencies` in the `package.json` instead of `dependencies` or `devDependencies`, e.g. in my case `react`:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "^16.8.6",
  ...
}
```

2. run `npm install`
3. build the library (in my case, with a `rollup -c` npm script

**In my main app**:

4. change the version of my library to point to my local project with a  relative path in `package.json`, e.g.

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-library": "file:../../libraries/my-library",
  ...
}
```

5. Add `resolve.symlinks = false` to my main app's webpack configuration
6. Add `--preserve-symlinks-main` and `--preserve-symlinks` to my `package.json` start script, e.g:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "set WEBPACK_CONFIG_FILE=all&& webpack",
  "start": "set WEBPACK_CONFIG_FILE=all&& webpack && node --preserve-symlinks-main --preserve-symlinks dist/server.js",
}
```

7. run `npm install`
8. run `npm run start`

Answer (score -1):

Okay guys, this is specific to my use case, but make sure to follow all the instructions to completely build the library you are symlinking. Initially, I a npm install and gulp build, but that wasn't enough. I had to run a few extra commands to get the library to fully build.

Now it works! If you are still having issues, go through the documentation for each library you are symlinking, and use my webpack config as a template for resolving external libraries.